# size_t in Go without using cgo

Tags: go, struct, cgo

This is a **C** **struct** that I want to port into **Go struct**:

```
struct InputBuffer_t {
   char* buffer;
   size_t buffer_length;
   ssize_t input_length;
};
```

But there is a way to declare **buffer_length** variable without using **C.size_t cgo pointer** in **Go**.

This is a concern for portability. If I write the **Go struct** in this way, is it will be portable?

```
type InputBuffer struct {
   Buffer        string
   BufferLength uint32
   InputLength  uint32
};
```

Comment: It's portable. Although your variable names are not idiomatic Go :)

Comment: Notice that in 64 bit systems, size_t is not uint32 but uint64, and ssize_t is equivalent to int64

Comment: If you want a type that changes based on the bitness of the target system, just use `int`.